# How to keep running my android app when phone goes standby?

Tags: android

Hi i'm programming an app that reads sensors values, and I need that it continue saving data while the phone goes standby (the screen go black after 1 minute). Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As P10 said Service is best.

And depending on how frequent you want to collect new data, a [wake lock](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) may be in order, to wake the phone from sleep. This of course can reduce battery saving sleep time so use wake locks sparingly.

Answer (score 3):

Make your code to be in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: Beyond that, you will need a `WakeLock`, since a service does not magically keep the CPU running. And, bear in mind that reading the sensor values and keeping the CPU running all the time will seriously drain the battery.